# Is it possible to create a C++ library that could be deployed on iOS/Android/HoloLens that use Core Location (or equivalent)?

Tags: c++, cross-platform, libraries

If you wanted to build a C++ library that could be used across multiple platforms. Say, "GPS streamer" that you can build and deploy on any platform and it will stream GPS data to a configured endpoint. Could you include interfaces for platforms like iOS that require an app to be running to use Core Location? How would you make that happen or is that not something you can do with hardware-specific libraries? Could you have many interfaces in the same C++ library that would allow it to be deployed anywhere it has an interface included in the repo?

Comment: Separate the platform specific code from the core code and then link the required bit together for each platform. eg libs iOSHalLib, AndroidHalLib, Win10HalLib, CoreLib, then just link each Hal library with the CoreLib to make the 3 platform modules.

Comment: Really appreciate it @RichardCritten! Still a bit fuzzy on how that will actually work. So let's say I write the iOS interface that pulls GPS data, and the C++ library sends it out. Do I write the GPS interface in Swift/Objective-C or do I run it in C++? And when you say "link" (iOSHalLib and CoreLib), do you mean compile separate libraries and link them together, or is the whole project compiled at once in XCode?